# Bash uppercase words that start with non-latin letters

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to Uppercase the first word of each line in a file. To do so, I can use one of the following commands:

`sed 's/^./\u&/'`

`sed -E 's/[[:alpha:]]+/\u&/1'`

However, these commands do not uppercase words that start with non-latin letter such as
`ängstlich`.

I tried exporting LC_ALL=C, but this did not solve the issue.

How can this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

```
echo "ängstlich" | LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 sed -E 's/[[:alpha:]]+/\u&/1'
```

Output:

```
Ängstlich
```